# $p * z - q * n = 1 \implies \gcd{(z,n)} = 1$

Tags: prime-numbers

Prove that:

let n $\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ z \leq n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\exists p,q \in \mathbb{Z}: p * z - q * n = 1 \implies \gcd{(z,n)} = 1$

Comment: Isn't this a consequence of Bezout Theorem?

Comment: You forgot the dollars in the heading...also use `$\gcd$` to get $\operatorname{gcd}(z,n)$

Comment: If $d|z,n$, then $d|pz-qn=1$

Comment: Im not familiar with bezouts theorem, but ill check it out

Comment: Actually Bezout's theorem is a consequence of this.  But note  $\gcd(n,z)|n$ and $\gcd(n,z)|z$ so $\gcd(n,z)$ will divide any $pn + qz$.  SO if *any* $pn + qz = 1$ then $\gcd(n,z)|1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\gcd(n,z)|n$ and $\gcd(n,z)|z$ so $\gcd(n,z)| pz - qn$ for all $p,q\in \mathbb Z$.

SO if there is any $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ so that $pn-qz = 1$ then $\gcd(n,z)|1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ c$ be a common divisor of $  z $ and $ n $.

$$c|z \wedge c|n \implies $$

$$c|pz \wedge c|qn \implies$$

$$c|(pz-qn) \implies $$
$$c|1 \implies $$
$$|c|=1 \implies$$
$$gcd(z,n)=1$$